# How to open a review in browser by passing an existing auth token

Tags: rest, authentication, python-2.7, atlassian-crucible

I have written a python script to login to crucible to access various APIs, The script works fine and returns a resposne token .

I can successfully call crucible rest API and create a review using FEAUTH=token.

Now I want to open this particluar review in browser window so that user can provide various other information.

**Code sample is :**

```
auth = urllib.urlencode({'FEAUTH': token})

url = "fisheye/cru/"+permaId+"?" auth

webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

The browser window opens but asks for a login.

Can someone please let me know how can I open this URL using an existing authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this

```
http://<your url>?access_token=7f813af1-381d-4dd7-b70b-b6a8399b2c00
```